# Crystal Report Conditional Page Break Formula

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have a cross tab report based off a single table. The report is rather easy, but I have some constraints on the Page Break. My data looks like this:

Each Sample can have one or multiple tests and each test can have one to three results. In the example below, Sodium Test has only one result; Urea and Calcium have two results each and Index has 3 results.

```
SAMPLE_NUMBER   TEST_NAME   RESULT_NAME         RESULT_VALUE
1       Calcium     Calcium Percentage            5
1       Calcium     Calcium Indirect Percentage   5
1       Sodium      Sodium Percentage             5
1       Urea        Urea Percentage               5
1       Urea        Urea Indirect Percentage      5
1       Index       Result 1                      5
1       Index       Result 2                      5
1       Index       Result 3                      5
```

I have a limitation where I can fit only 4 columns on my report page. The report has the Sample Number in the Rows and the Test and Result Names in the Columns. The result value is the Summary Value. 
Since one column on the Cross Tab is occupied by the sample number, it leaves only 3 columns for my results.

I want to break my data in such a way that all the results a test are grouped together. If the columns do not fit, I want the page to break. In this case, I want Calcium and Sodium to be grouped together. Urea will be on a separate page and Index will be on a separate page.

How can I write such a formula in Crystal? You help is much much appreciated !!! I am expected to demo this report next week !! I have a representation of the image attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your data contains only calcium, sodium, urea and index... then approach you can follow is take 3 sections (Assuming you place in Report Footer 3 sections are (`Report Footera, Report Footerb and Report Footerc`)).

Place 3 cross tabs in 3 sections and then for each section check the option `New Page After` in section expert.

```
In first crosstab take Calcium and Sodium
In second crosstab take urea and 
In third crosstab take index
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I can have variable number of tests. I cannot hardcode number of sections.